# A ball in $H^m(\Omega)$ is closed under $L^2$-convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, hilbert-spaces, sequence-of-function, closed-map

I read it in a paper in which the author aims to claim that if a sequence $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $H^m(\Omega)$ (here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain), and $u_n$ has a limit $u$ in $L^2$ norm, then $u$ is in $H^m(\Omega)$.
I don't know why it stands. please help me understand it.

Comment: The closed ball $B(0,r)$ in the Hilbert space $H=H^m(\Omega)$ is weakly compact  and hence weakly closed and thus closed in every Hausdorff locally convex space in which $H$ embeds continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{ u_n \}$ is bounded in $H^m(\Omega)$, it has a subsequence $\{ u_{\varphi(n)} \}$ which converges weakly in $H^m(\Omega)$ towards some $v \in H^m(\Omega)$. Hence, $\{ u_{\varphi(n)} \}$ converges strongly towards $v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. By uniqueness of the limit, you have $u = v$. Hence $u \in H^m(\Omega)$.

However, of course, this does not imply that $\{ u_n \}$ converges to $u$ for the $H^m(\Omega)$ topology.

Comment: Oh, I see! $\{u_{\phi(n)}\}$ converges strongly towards $v$ is due to the compact embedding, right?

Comment: Yes that is how I wrote it above. On second thought, you could also say that 1) $\{ u_n \}$ converges weakly to $u$ in $L^2$ and 2) $\{ u_{\varphi(n)} \}$ converges weakly to $v$ in $H^m$ so also weakly in $L^2$. Then conclude by uniqueness of weak limit.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks, it is very helpful.